# Why is Google Maps scrolling slowly with small number of Markers?

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, google-maps-markers

With 5-10 markers on screen, google maps for android is very slow. With ~100, it's almost unusable. I've searched far and wide, but I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem. People discussing the javascript API seem to think thousands of markers is reasonable, so I figure I must be doing something wrong here on android.

To be clear, adding the markers is fine, but once they are on screen, panning around is horribly slow. I turned on the "Profile GPU Rendering" setting and the frames which have markers present take significantly longer to render.

I'm using `play-services-maps 11.6.0`

Here's the code. I'm just adding markers once in the activity.

```
fun addMarkers(latLngs: List<LatLng>){
    for (latLng in latLngs){
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_marker_red)))
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testapp.TrackVehicleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/track_vehicle_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/trackVehiclesMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea what could be going on here, or further debugging tips? The only thing I can think of is that my layout is somehow screwed up. Thanks!

Edit: I'm testing this on a Moto G4 plus, so I don't think it's just a matter of the phone being slow

Comment: Where `addMarkers()` called?

Comment: Just once inside `onMapReady`